# NumberFormatException in setTag(int key, Object tag) method

Tags: android, imageview, numberformatexception

I'm trying to set a tag to an ImageView. But I got this exception:

**NumberFormatException:Invalid int: "TAGTEST"**

this is my code:

```
public static final String FIRST_TAG = "TAGTEST";
imageView.setTag(Integer.parseInt(FIRST_TAG.toString()), myIndex);
```

Why this code doesn't work???

`Integer.parseInt(FIRST_TAG.toString())`

Comment: Because `"TAGTEST"` is not a number. As a side note, `setTag(int, Object)` probably isn't going to work like you're thinking.

Comment: I tried to parse it to an integer by parseInt()!!

Comment: It's not going to parse unless the stuff in between the quotes is a __number__; specifically an integer. For example: `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key has to be an Android ID.

You can use a `R.id.somethingfromyourviews`

Or

Create an ID in an xml file, usually called `ids.xml` located at `res\values`

```
 <resources>
    <item type="id" value="integer" name="your_id_name"/>
 </resources>
```

So you use it in code `R.id.your_id_name`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert a String into an Integer, and that has triggered that exception.